# C++ Construct from pointer

Tags: c++, c, gcc, visual-c++, constructor

I am trying to make my project complied with GCC to link with library compiled with MSVC (that I have no sources for). The problem is that this library also exists for linux x86, x86_64 and arm platforms compiled with GCC (and my project is crossplatform) and I do not want to write a lot of platform-dependent (and compiler-dependent) code. Also other libraries linked to project are designed to be compiled by GCC (like ffmpeg and vlc) and I have no possibility to migrate to MSVC.
For that I've written C-style wrapper library (based on original headers).

Constructors and destructors for classes are done this way:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void* myClass_myClass()
{
    void* ptr = new myClass();
    return ptr;
}
__declspec(dllexport) void myClass_unmyClass(void* ptr)
{
    delete((myClass*)ptr);
}
```

This part is compiled with MSVC and linked to original library. As you see (and I can see it in dependency walker) I have c-style exports that I can link with GCC. It allocates memory, creates object and acts as designed.

Now I am writing second part of this wrapper that will contain classes and will be compiled with GCC and linked to my project. It should be based on original headers of library (to make sure it acts the same as original with both linux- and windows- versions of this library). And I am in doubts how to make constructor and destructor of classes.
Let's say we have

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    ~MyClass()
}
```

in original header.

How it can be defined in .cpp to bypass call to my c-style "consturctor" and "destructor" (so they will bypass calls to original constructors and destructors)?
It would be great to assign pointer to `this` in constructor, but it is forbidden.

P.S. I have no internals of classes. They all have

```
private: myClassImpl* m_pImpl;
```

so I can't use copy constructor. Even if I could - I do not want to construct 2 times the same object.

Comment: What do you mean by "bypass"? Also there is no reason to use `void*`. Use `MyClass*`. If you need it to be understood by pure C, you can use `struct MyClass*` (or use a typedef).

Comment: @ymett I mean to call my C-style "constructor" somehow form original constructor of myClass and take returned pointer as pointer to created class.
Maybe you are right about using `myClass*` instead of `void*` but how can this be done if there is no such thing as "pointer to class" in C?

Comment: I don't think "bypass" is the word you want. Struct and class are the same thing in C++ and C has pointer-to-struct.

Comment: @ymett yeah, you are right, I meant to forward the call toanother function.
Ok, even if they are the same - this is not what I am trying to do. What I am trying to do is to call native constructor defined in original header and make it take the pointer to object returned form myClass_myClass as freshly constructed object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wrapper class should be a handle class which calls `myClass_myClass()` in the constructor, stores the returned pointer as a member, and calls `myClass_unmyClass()` in the destructor on the stored pointer. All member functions in the original class should be copied in the wrapper, but just call the original functions (via wrapper "C" functions) on the stored pointer. Be careful with copy-constructors and copy-assignment operators -- the defaults won't do the right thing. You must either delete them or implement them to call appropriate wrapper "C" functions.

Comment: This is good solution, I thought about it. But the idea was not to change original headers of library (because as I said there is linux version of this library with same classes that works just fine). 
But! maybe I can use that myClassImpl* m_pImpl variables to store this pointers.
This will call constructor 2 times (one for wrapper class and one for original class) that I was trying to avoid, but anyway it may do the trick.